# Purpose of assigning None to variables

Tags: python, if-statement, nonetype

I was looking at the answers for a practice exam and this was a suggested answer for one of the questions:

```
def multipal(word,n=None):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[:i] == word[i-1::-1]:
            repeat = word[:i]
            if not n:
                no_repeats = len(word)/i
            else:
                no_repeats = n
            if word == repeat * no_repeats:
                return True
    return False
```

The purpose of this function is to determine if the input word is a palindrome (a word that is read the same from the front as it is from the back e.g. 'aza' or 'abba') of 'n' repeats. For example, `multipal('abaaba', 2)` will return `True` but `multipal('abaaba', 3)` will return `False`.

---

What I want to know is why `n` is assigned `None` in the original argument and does it actually affect the rest of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning something to a function parameter makes it an optional parameter. So you can leave it out when calling the function. In your case, you could call `multipal('babbab')` and `n` would get the default value `None` (because that’s how it was set up in the function definition).

As for how this affects your function, just look at where `n` is used:

```
if not n:
    no_repeats = len(word)/i
else:
    no_repeats = n
```

So if `n` has a falsish value (e.g. `None`, or `0`), then the first case will be used which assigns a dynamical repeat count.